# How to get all the elements in the list without an element at a specific index in python?

Tags: python

How one could get all the elements in a list without an element at a certain index
   in a python list.
   Would be great if there is an fast and easy way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Could anyone please tell that why is it off-topic??? @larsmans, martineau, Haidro, Michael0x2a, shanabus

Comment: Did you read the message in the grey box? If not, nobody's going to reply to you, because if you won't read that message, what are the odds you're going to read a reply? If you read it, but there's something you don't understand, or you disagree about why it applies here, then ask something specific in the comment. (Also, an "@" with 5 names after it like that isn't going to show up as a notification for any of them, so it's unlikely they'd reply anyway.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume

```
elements  # list of values
n  # unwanted element index
```

then you can do

```
result = elements[:n] + elements[n+1:]
```

or

```
result = elements[:]  # copy
del result[n]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to do it besides slicing:

```
def exclude(iterable, index):
    return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(iterable) if i != index]
```

So, what's the advantage?

Well, it works with any iterable, not just sequences… but that's not a big deal; you usually don't have indexes when you're dealing with a generator or a dict… (Also, you could get that more easily just by using `islice` instead of slicing.)

However, it's easy to generalize to multiple indices, which could be a big deal if you might ever want that:

```
def exclude(iterable, *indices):
    indices = set(indices)
    return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(iterable) if i not in indices]
```

But if you *won't* ever want that, it's just extra complexity for no good reason, so go with the slicing.

Comment: It is overhead for such simple action. `my_list[:i] + my_list[i+1:]` is enough.

Comment: @AntonEgorov: My answer explains what the benefits are, and concludes that "if you won't ever want that, it's just extra complexity for no good reason, so go with the slicing". So what do you think your comment adds?

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> exclude = lambda l, i: l[:i] + l[i+1:]
>>> exclude(lst, 3)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: Why would you use `lambda` to define a named function? The only advantages of `lambda` are that you can use it in an expression (which doesn't apply, because you're using it in a statement) and you don't have to give it a name (which doesn't apply, because you're giving it a name).

Comment: I use `lambda` here because: 1. It is oneline and easy to use in interactive python; 2. It is simple as the question answered

Comment: `def exclude(l, i): return l[:i] + l[i+1:]` is also one line, and also easy to use in interactive Python, and more readable and idiomatic.

Comment: It does not matter how to define a function here, it's just an example, dude.

Comment: Writing code that's less readable and less pythonic for no good reason does not make for a good example.

Comment: It seems that you never write real code, and dont know difference between *level 0* question answer and real code. Gratz, you've read 'Diving into Python'.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "level 0", but the reason I know not to intentionally write non-pythonic code is because I write and maintain large code bases in Python, and I know what it costs to have to figure out your code a few months after you wrote it.